# How to get the value of the passed data from <Link/> component in my next functional component page in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have two pages, i want to pass data from one functional component to the other, i am trying to achieve this by using `<Link/>` but i don't know how i would retrieve this in my other page:

here is my code:

FirstPage:

```
const CustomerListResults = () => {
             <Link
                to={{
                pathname: "/app/CustomerDetails",
                data: id // your data array of objects
                }}>

                <Button
                  color="primary"
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Expand
                </Button>
              </Link>
}
```

My Second Page that i need the data in:

```
const CustomerProfile = () => {
      // here i want to get the id i passed in the <Link/> component
}
```

my Routes.js file:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    element: <DashboardLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'account', element: <Account /> },
      { path: 'customers', element: <CustomerList /> },
      { path: 'CustomerDetails', element: <CustomerDetails /> },
      { path: 'ReportDetails', element: <ReportDetails /> },
      { path: 'report', element: <ReportList /> },
      { path: 'freight', element: <FreightList /> },
      { path: 'dashboard', element: <Dashboard /> },
      { path: 'analytics', element: <Analytics /> },
      { path: 'products', element: <ProductList /> },
      { path: 'settings', element: <Settings /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <MainLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', element: <Login /> },
      { path: 'register', element: <Register /> },
      // { path: '404', element: <NotFound /> },
      { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/login" /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/app/dashboard" /> }
    ]
  }
];

export default routes;
```

Comment: Just send as props

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV can u give me an example code for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you want to pass data from Pages linked with the Router, Route and Link.

To accomplish that I use 'react-router-dom' insthead of 'react-router'.

When I am on a Page and I programmatically push another with : history.push() you can even pass the state, and inside that you can put whatever object you want.

To retrive it on the other Page you have to use : useLocation().state

It will return the state object passed before. So basically you can go like :

history.push({location:"path/to/next/page", state : { obj : "value1",obj2 : "value2"});

and in the next page you can destructure at the start like :

const {obj,obj2} = useLocation().state;

I'm sorry I can't use the "code mode" because I'm from mobile.

Comment: do i import usehistory from react-router-dom? or from react?

Comment: react-router-dom

Comment: it tells me that it shouldn't be imported from here

Comment: Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: I confirm that useHistory can be imported from 'react-router-dom' code : import {useLocation,useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

Answer (score -1):

Are you using react-router `<Link />`? If you are you can use its `useParams()` like this:

```js
function BlogPost() {
  let { slug } = useParams();
  return <div>Now showing post {slug}</div>;
}
```

you can find the docs [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)

Comment: when i try to import Link from react-router it gives me an error and says "attempted import error:  Link is not exported from react-router"

Comment: i tried this i still get undefined for the id in my second page in the console.

Comment: also in which page should i put the reactDOM.render method?

Comment: you should import it from `react-router-dom`

Comment: For the rest of your questions, you will need `ReactDOM.render` only *once* in the index.js file. These parts usually go in your **Root** file like `App.js`